# Why Chrome emits PointerEvents and Firefox MouseEvents and which type definition should I use in my code

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, firefox, mouseevent

I'm somewhat new to typescript and try to add type definitions to all my methods while being as precise as possible.

When I click in Chrome a `PointerEvent` is emitted. In Firefox a `MouseEvent` is emitted.
I know that `PointerEvent` extends `MouseEvent` and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent#browser_compatibility Firefox also supports these.

1. Why does chrome emit a different event than Firefox
2. Which type should I use in my event listeners (probably `MouseEvent`)
3. and most importantly, how do I determine that if both show something different? (a.k.a is it safe to trust chrome or do I have to consult the documentation?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1675847

And in Safari too: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218665

According to the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-click
it's supposed to be a `PointerEvent`

So until these bugs are fixed just use `MouseEvent` since `PointerEvent` inherits from `MouseEvent` (https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents3/#pointerevent-interface)

Comment: just want to mention a point of confusion is that the MDN docs [specify that click is a MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event). also, it seems `dblclick` in W3C spec is part of MouseEvent, not PointerEvent..